# Is it possible to digitally sign a Flex application?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, digital-signature, signing

We keep getting dinged by our security team because we don't sign our Flex applications. As far as I know, it's not possible to sign a Flex application, but it *is* possible to sign an AIR application. Does anyone know of a way to do this for Flex web applications (swfs) or Flex libraries (swcs)?

My initial thought is, "what's the point?" since I can't see any way for a user to actually verify that a swf file was signed by us, rendering any kind of signing pointless. Am I missing something? The closest thing I've seen to this is how Adobe signs their framework RSLs so they can get cached and they can know for sure the functionality in each swz file is the same, but all those caching features are built into Flash player and have nothing to do with what a client can actually do to verify a projects source.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're question is; and it sounds like you have a good understanding of things.  I've never heard of "signing a Flex Application". You are right the signed SWZs files are special files created by Adobe cached by the Flash Player across multiple domains. They do not expose that functionality to users [I assume for security reasons].  Does your app need to share Flash Libraries across multiple domains?  Perhaps they just need you to serve the SWF over an HTTPS connection?

Comment: The question is: can you sign a Flex Application in the same way you can sign an Air application? I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I can't find any definitive information (understandably) on the topic so I'm just looking for *any* kind of authoritative source or just some more ammo to show why this is a dumb requirement.

Comment: In that case; the answer is formally "No".  NitroLM had an interesting licensing scheme that had to do with encrypting SWFs and loading them using a specialized Flash Loader; however the loader would still be unencrypted.  I do not believe that their approach is the same as signing a SWF.

Comment: You can sign any file (using pgp, gig etc) and then provide the .asc file so that it can be confirmed manually. This is what Apache Software Foundation does with all of it releases so that might be enough to keep your security team happy.